# ¿Como actualizo un editText de un fragment desde otro fragment en un activity Tabbed?

Tags: java, android-studio

Buenos dias, tengo un tabbed activity con tres fragment, uno de ellos se llama frPrincipal y otro se llama frConfiguracion.
En el frConfiguracion tengo un editText donde ingreso una ip y un boton con el que lo guardo usando SharedPreferences. Pero no soy capaz de que cuando se guarde el dato se vea reflejado en otro editText del frPrincipal. me toca cerrar la aplicacion y volverla a abrir para poder que se vea reflejado el dato.

Esto es lo que tengo en el boton del frConfiguracion

```
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    //debemos declarar esto para poder instanciar los objetos en el fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fr_configuracion,container,false);

    if(rootView != null){
        final EditText etConfigDirIP = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etConfigDirIP);
        Button btnConfigGuardar = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnConfigGuardar);

        //Traigo la IP anteriormente guardada
        SharedPreferences sharpref  = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String valor = sharpref.getString("Dir_IP", "NO hay ip");
        etConfigDirIP.setText(valor.toString());

        btnConfigGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Utilizo el shared preferences para poder guardar los datos

                SharedPreferences sharpref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharpref.edit();
                editor.putString("Dir_IP",etConfigDirIP.getText().toString());
                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "IP Guardada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                //Pendiente que al guardar actualice la IP en el fragment principal

            }
        });
    }
    return  rootView;
}
```

Y ésto es lo que tengo en el frPrincipal

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fr_principal,container,false);

    if(rootView != null){
        //Instanciar
        final EditText etPpalDirIP = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etPpalDirIP);
        final EditText etPpalDirCasa = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etPpalDirCasa);
        final EditText etPpalComando = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etPpalComando);
        final EditText etPpalMandar = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etPpalMandar);
        final EditText etPpalRespuesta = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etPpalResultado);

        Button btnMandar = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnPpalMandar);


        //Traigo la IP guardada en configuracion, mirar si se puede traer desde el edit text de configuracion
        SharedPreferences sharpref  = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String valor = sharpref.getString("Dir_IP", "NO hay ip");
        etPpalDirIP.setText(valor.toString());

        //Metodo oncliclistener del boton
        btnMandar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String mensaje;
                mensaje = etPpalDirIP.getText().toString() + "?"; //el interrogante es para separar el comando completo
                mensaje = mensaje + etPpalDirCasa.getText().toString() + etPpalComando.getText().toString();
                etPpalMandar.setText(mensaje);

                //llamo el subprograma que manda al servidor
                new MandarDatos().execute(mensaje);

                //llevar el valor de la respuesta al edittext

            }
        });

    }
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estoy seguro que hay una forma más fácil y rápida pero no se porqué siempre me voy por el lado más difícil :p.

Lo que se me ocurre es que al botón de configurar puedes pasar los datos de tu `fragment x` a tu `fragment y` y ya después ya los guardas en `sharedPreferences`:

```
FragmentX fragmentX = new FragmentX();
Bundle datos = new Bundle();
datos.putString("IP", "192.168.0.1");// Aquí lo he puesto directamente el string
fragmentX .setArguments(datos);
```

En tu segundo fragmentY(tab) recibes los valores, lo seteas a tu `Edittext` y posteriormente guardas el valor en `SharedPreferences`, en este caso lo metí dentro de una función. Dentro de `Oncreateview` haces una comparación para verificar si existe un valor ya guardado:

```
sharpref  = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = sharpref.getString("Dir_IP",null);
if (value == null) {
    guardarEnPreferencias(); // Si está vacío que guarde
} else {
 //En caso contrario que cargue los datos guardado
  SharedPreferences sharpref  = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String valor = sharpref.getString("Dir_IP", "NO hay ip");
        etConfigDirIP.setText(valor.toString());

}

 //Ojo, este método va fuera del OnCreateView

     public void guardarEnPreferencias(){
      //Recibes el valor y lo seteas a tu edittext
      String valorRecibido = this.getArguments().getString("IP");
      etConfigDirIP.setText(valorRecibido.toString());

      SharedPreferences sharpref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharpref.edit();
      editor.putString("Dir_IP",etConfigDirIP.getText().toString());
      editor.commit();
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "IP Guardada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```